# Can't add new language - Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, language, input-languages

Can't add the language on Windows 10. Gets stuck with that loading circle and doesn't do anything. Restarting settings app and restarting the PC doesn't help. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What edition of Windows 10 do you have installed?  This this machine connected an enterprise AD domain?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it's working, but really really slow. I had to wait for about 5 minutes on this screen and then it worked properly. No idea what might have caused that as I have a proper internet connection.